# Im trying to add a play command to my discord bot but

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a play command to my discord bot so it can play music from youtube and maybe other places later but right now  i just tried getting it to play a audio file from my computer to test if i could make it join and play something before getting into the more complicated stuff like figuring out how to get it to play a song/audio from a youtube url

right now, this is what i have

```
Crashbot.on('message', async message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'play':
            if (message.member.voice.channel) {
                const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join().then(() => {

                    const dispatcher = connection.play('audio.mp3');

                    dispatcher.on('start', () => {

                    });

                    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

                })
            }
    }

})
```

and every time i run it i get this error

```
(node:18884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'connection' before initialization
    at C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Crashbot\index.js:213:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Crashbot\index.js:211:36)
(node:18884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18884) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `.then(...)`. Since there is an `await`, it runs well without `.then()`. And the `connection` is, in your code, the returned value of the promise. So it throws an error.

Try this code:

```js
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

const dispatcher = connection.play('audio.mp3');

dispatcher.on('start', () => {});

dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
```